# Unclosed SVG path appears to be closed

Tags: javascript, path, svg, d3.js

I am writing some stuff with d3 and I came across a a bizarre problem. Paths that are closed end with a 'Z' character, but every path I make closes ( and fills ) regardless of whether I include a Z or not. Even in isolation with examples copied from the spec this happens. For example:

```
<svg>
    <path d="M 40 60 L 10 60 L 40 42.68 M 60 60 L 90 60 L 60 42.68"/>
</svg>
```

I am baffled as to what the problem could be. I would appreciate any insight.

Comment: OK, the problem was that it was being filled which gave the appearance of closing the path.

So some boilerplate css for any svg work should include:

    path {
        fill: none;
    }

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The relevant line from the [SVG specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/), regarding [filling paths](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#FillProperties):

> The fill operation fills open subpaths by performing the fill operation as if an additional "closepath" command were added to the path to connect the last point of the subpath with the first point of the subpath.

So, as far as the **fill** is concerned, there's an implicit "Z" at the end. However, for the **stroke**, there's no implied closure, so it won't draw a stroke connecting the last point to the first point unless you explicitly add a "Z".

If you only want to apply a stroke, use CSS to disable the fill:

```
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

(I see you answered your own question, but I thought others might still find an explanation useful.)

Comment: In case this helps someone: `fill: transparent;` will close the path, but invisibly. The invisible area is then detectable by JavaScript (mouse events).

Comment: @FabianvonEllerts Or you could just add a Z...?

Answer (score 11):

I up-voted the answer, but sometimes css is not an option when you try to convert the svg to canvas and would like to prevent the svg path from filling or closing. Equivalent to the css solution but with no css...

```
<svg fill="white" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1.5">
    <path d="M 40 60 L 10 60 L 40 42.68 M 60 60 L 90 60 L 60 42.68"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: This answer with `fill-opacity="0"` saved me a lot of time, thanks

Comment: Thank you! For a path I never want filled, this is better than mucking around with CSS, which can have unintended side effects.