# D3 React - select element in map of elements using dynamic class name or selector: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll'

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I have written some code using SVG and D3 which works when I am using it to create / select one element in the DOM.

> selectorAll.js:7 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element': '.2ec41507-5bc3-46d8-aa9e-c1a1bdd87573' is not a valid selector.

Here is the code that works:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    nodes.forEach((el, idx) => {
        const svg = d3
            .select(svgRefs.current[idx])
            .attr('viewBox', `0 0 ${avaliableHorizontalSpace} ${avaliableHorizontalSpace}`);
        const line = d3.line<Number>()
            // number returned here is x position of each point
            .x((value, index) => (avaliableHorizontalSpace / (data.length - 1)) * index)
            // number returned here is y position of each point
            .y((value) => Number(value));
        svg.selectAll('path').data([data]).join('path').attr('d', (value) => line(value));
    });
}, [rects]);

...

{nodes.map((el, idx) => (
    <svg
        ref={(ref): void => { svgRefs.current[idx] = ref; }}
        style={{ position: 'absolute' }}
    >
        <path stroke="blue" fill="none" />
    </svg>
))}
```

And here is the code that doesn't work:

```js
const [nodes, setNodes] = useState<Array<{ node: number; id: string }>>([]);

...

useEffect(() => {
    nodes.forEach((el, idx) => {
        const svg = d3
            .select(svgRefs.current[idx])
            .attr('viewBox', `0 0 ${avaliableHorizontalSpace} ${avaliableHorizontalSpace}`);
        const line = d3.line<Number>()
            // number returned here is x position of each point
            .x((value, index) => (avaliableHorizontalSpace / (data.length - 1)) * index)
            // number returned here is y position of each point
            .y((value) => Number(value));
        svg.select(`.${nodes[idx].id}`).data([data]).join('path').attr('d', (value) => line(value));
    });
}, [rects]);

...

{nodes.map((el, idx) => (
    <svg
        ref={(ref): void => { svgRefs.current[idx] = ref; }}
        style={{ position: 'absolute' }}
    >
        <path className={nodes[idx].id} stroke="blue" fill="none" />
    </svg>
))}
```

The difference is that I'm using class names to try and select each single `<path />` element and am changing the use of `selectAll` to `select`.

I have checked that the ids are correct and matching which they are. I have tried adding quotes and changing the syntax but it is still throwing the error.

How can I select each individual path using a dynamic identifier successfully?

#### Update:

I have discovered that this works sometimes if I wrap the `select` in a `setTimeout`:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    const line = d3.line<Number>()
        // number returned here is x position of each point
        .x((value, index) => (avaliableHorizontalSpace / (data.length - 1)) * index)
        // number returned here is y position of each point
        .y((value) => Number(value));
    svg.select(`.${nodes[idx].id}`).data([data]).join('path').attr('d', (value) => line(value));
}, 300);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class name is not a good selector in your case.
Add an attribute (for example `node-id`) to your element:

```
<path className="node" nodeId={nodes[idx].id} ... />
```

, and select it by that attribute later:

```
svg.select(`.node[node-id='${nodes[idx].id}']`);
```

**UPD**: Since with deal with TypeScript, here is a workaround:

```
import { SVGProps } from 'react';

interface INodePathWithId extends SVGProps<SVGPathElement> {
  nodeId: number;
} 

const NodePathWithId = (props : INodePathWithId) => (<path {...props}/>);

...
<NodePathWithId nodeId={1} fill="red" stroke="blue" />
...
```

Comment: Thank you - I have tried but TypeScript is throwing an error: `Type '{ nodeId: string; stroke: string; fill: string; }' is not assignable to type 'SVGProps<SVGPathElement>'.
  Property 'nodeId' does not exist on type 'SVGProps<SVGPathElement>'`. Do you know if there is a supported type for `nodeId`?

Comment: You can define `SVGPathElementWidthId`... (one more reason to hate TypeScript)... or cast it as `any`

Comment: Thanks! Yes - but if the prop doesn't exist how can I cast it? `<path nodeId={nodes[idx].id} as any stroke="blue" fill="none" />`, `<path nodeId={nodes[idx].id as any} stroke="blue" fill="none" />` does not work :(

Comment: @Mr.Robot see an update to my answer. Hope it helps...

Comment: This worked!! Thanks!! Although I had to change `select` to `selectAll` and I also then came across this problem but the second answer ficed it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213155/unclosed-svg-path-appears-to-be-closed/10213649#10213649

Comment: Glad to help :)